# Measure of a Brownian motion = normal distribution?

Tags: brownian-motion, risk-neutral-measure, normal-distribution, self-study

Consider some model where the process increments are normally distributed, e.g. Vasicek:
$$dr(t) = \left(\theta - ar(t)\right)dt + \sigma dW(t).$$

We usually say that $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion under a measure $\mathbb P$. $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion if, among other conditions, $W(t) \sim N(0, t)$ given $W(0)=0$. Does it mean that the measure $\mathbb P$ is actually a normal distribution, i.e.
$$\mathbb P\left(\frac{W(t)}{\sqrt t} \in [a ,b]\right) = \Phi(b) - \Phi(a)$$ where $\Phi(\cdot)$ denotes the CDF of a standard normal random variable?

Comment: The equation you wrote is correct. But it is only one example of the properties of the measure P. The measure P is more general than this and cannot be said "to be a normal distribution", but the normal distribution does come up in describing the measure. The measure applies to a stochastic procees, the normal distribution applies to a random variable, so they cannot be identical.

Answer (score 6):

1. It is correct that
   $$
   \mathbf{P}(t^{-1/2}W(t)  \in[a,b])=Φ(b)−Φ(a),  \forall t\in(0,\infty) 
   $$
   due to the stationary increments property of the Wiener process and the fact that you normalized the random variable by dividing by its standard deviation.
2. $\mathbf{P}$ is a probability measure on an abstract space, not a random variable. Hence, you probably mean that $W(t)$ is normally distributed under $\mathbf{P}$, NOT $\mathbf{P}$ is normally distributed. People tend to mention the probability measure, for if you change it the process will no longer be Gaussian.

Comment: Welcome to Quant SE. No need for comments :) This is (along with the rest of your answers) acceptable as an answer to the question.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on “...measure on an abstract space”. Normal distribution is also a measure (of a rv). Also I could change to martingale measure $\mathbb Q$ and my process still would be Gaussian, i.e. $dW^{\mathbb Q}= dW^{\mathbb P} +\lambda dt$ by Girsanov.

Comment: @tosik. A probability space is a triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P})$ where $\Omega$ is an abstract space. A normal distribution is a very specific type (with a specific density) on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n \geq 1$. A random variable or vector $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be normal if it induces a normal distribution on the range space.

Comment: @tosik. You might want to be precise with Girsanov's Theorem so as not conflate related but different concepts. If $W_{t}$ is a Brownian Motion under $\mathbf{P}$, the newly defined process $Z_{t} = W_{t} - \int_{0}^{t} \theta_{s} ds$ is no longer a BM under $\mathbf{P}$. Girsanov's Thm tells you how to construct a new measure so as that $Z_{t}$ becomes a BM.

Comment: I agree that $Z_t$ is no longer BM under $\mathbb P$ but I think you agree that it is Gaussian both under $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q$. I indeed probably confuse measures on $\Omega$ with distributions on $\mathbf R$. Your answer (and comments) do shed some light but I still don't have a clear picture. So, $\Omega$ is an abstract space where for each $\omega \in \Omega$ there is an associated function $f$ that we think of as a stochastic process? Can you elaborate more on the link between $\mathbb P$ and normal distribution for the case of BM?

Comment: @tosik we think of it as a real-value function known as random variable. A stochastic process is defined with respect to a filtration, and at each time $t$ it is a rv. As a concept, the Gaussian distribution is not exactly the same as Gaussian measure. The Gaussian distribution is formaly constructed via the canonical Gaussian (probability) measure. The space $\Omega$ defines the domain of a function that returns a number in $[0,1]$, which is the probability distribution. In short, the Gaussian measure defines the Gaussian probability distribution.

Comment: @tosik. I will try to address the last sentence in your previous comment. Gaussian measures are defined on euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Strictly speaking one just need a Banach space, but let's keep things simple). There is no way to define a Gaussian measure on an abstract space $\Omega$. A Brownian motion (could be multi-dimensional) $W: \Omega \times [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is the connection. I hope this clarifies.